# jquery append - method Issue - how to solve it?

Tags: jquery

I am getting data from Json, using $.map, method. and according to the type of data, i am making the element and appending to the container what data says. it works fine all browsers, including ie9. but less that ie 9, i am not getting any thing at all.

how can i fix this?

my code :

```
var processModules = function (mData) {
    var lMData = mData;
    $.map(lMData, function (mVal,i) {
            $(mVal.type === 'form' ?  '<form></form>' : '<div></div>',{
                id : mVal.attributes.id,
                'class' : mVal.attributes['class']
            })
            .appendTo(mVal.container);    // not appending in less than ie9.  
    } )
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   $.getJSON('json.txt', function (data) {
        if($(data['modules'])){
            processModules($(data['modules']));
        }
   })   
});
```

my json :

```
 "modules":[
      {
         "type":"navigation",
         "container":"#header",
         "title":"Top Navigation",
         "attributes":{
            "class":"topNavigation",
            "id":"topNavigation"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"content",
         "title":"Hi Welcome to mobile development",
         "subtitle":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
         "container":"#maincontent",
         "attributes":{
            "class":"topContent"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"form",
         "title":"Registration Form",
         "action":"submit.aspx",
         "name":"registrationform",
         "container":"#maincontent",
         "attributes":{
            "class":"registrationform"
         },
         "fields":[
            {
               "id":"firstname",
               "label":"First Name",
               "name":"fname",
               "type":"text",
               "value":""
            },
            {
               "id":"email",
               "label":"Email",
               "name":"email",
               "type":"text",
               "value":""
            },
            {
               "id":"countries",
               "label":"Country",
               "name":"countries",
               "type":"select",
               "options":[
                  {
                     "value":"",
                     "text":"Select Country"
                  },
                  {
                     "value":"in",
                     "text":"India",
                      "selected":"true"
                  },
                  {
                     "value":"us",
                     "text":"United Stated"

                  },
                  {
                     "value":"uk",
                     "text":"United Kingdom"
                  },
                  {
                     "value":"cn",
                     "text":"Canada"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"submit",
               "name":"submit",
               "type":"submit",
               "value":"Submit"
            }
         ]
```

Comment: you need to prove that `processModules` is even getting called on IE <9  It's far more likely an AJAX failure than `.append()` not working.

Comment: Sidenote: why `$.map` instead of the more descriptive `$.each`?

Comment: @3gwebtrain `$.map()` is used to create a new array from an input array - the callback should `return` the value of each new element.  Use `$.each` instead if all you are doing is iterating over the elements.

Comment: thanks, let me try, and get back to you.

Comment: still no luck. as well i each, or map both are consoling the data properly. but element alone not appending.

Comment: so what does `mVal.container` have in it?  An element ID ?

Comment: yes, the data containing element id's

Comment: i updated my json code as well. pls have a look, if needed. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can't name an object literal property `class` without enclosing it in quotes, because `class` is a reserved word in JS. Change:

```
class : mVal.attributes.class
```

to

```
'class' : mVal.attributes.class
```

Other browsers allow it (though it's always puzzled me a bit why they do - if it was a variable, rather than a property, after all, it would error).

Generally, avoid reserved words in your own definitions.

Comment: Well then as @Alnitak says, first check that the function is getting called at all.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your function is even being called (and it's quite possible that it isn't)
 you need to wrap the `class` key in quotes, to ensure it's not hitting reserved keyword clash rules.

You'll need to do this for the value, too:

```
'class': mVal.attributes['class']
```

using the `[]` syntax because `myobject.'mykey'` isn't legal syntax either.

You've also got an extraneous jQuery wrapper in your code:

```
if ($(data['modules'])) { ... }
```

which is wrong because the modules variable is an array of objects, not DOM elements.

I would just write the whole thing as:

```
var processModules = function(data) {
    var lMData = data.modules || [];  // default to empty array
    $.map(lMData, function (mVal,i) {
        $(mVal.type === 'form' ?  '<form>' : '<div>', mVal.attributes);
        .appendTo(mVal.container);
    })
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   $.getJSON('json.txt', processModules);
});
```

Note that I've not created a new attribute object, since the one in your JSON is already legal for supply direct to `$()`.

If after all that it *still* doesn't work in IE9 then you need to do much more debugging and satisfy us here that the `.appendTo` call is *really* getting called with the appropriate parameters.  It's unthinkable that a core jQuery function would simply fail to work.

Comment: Weren't you just lamenting someone posting the same answer but a min or two after? :)

Comment: three minutes after, in that case, which seemed likely long enough for my answer to have appeared ;-)